# jQuery mobile listview data-split change right button into text

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, button

How can I make the data split list view right button as picture below:

[image: default mode]

into text like the picture below:

[image: custom right button into text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dcs6w/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#custom-btn').find('.ui-btn-inner span').last().removeClass('ui-icon').text('M+');
});
```